# Trying to handle web table in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hello to all my mentors on here. Please help me go through this.

I tried two options as saved in frame1, both showing errors.

```
    // I wanted to follow this instruction.
    // switch to the frame that has the table
    // get num of rows
    // get numb of column
    // iterate rows and columns and get text and print
```

I am self-studying for automated testing using Selenium with Java, lately though people have recommended that I switch to C#, as it is easier. Please advise.

```
package UI;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;

public class DynamicWebtable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\browserdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://uk.investing.com/charts/stocks-charts");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"onetrust-accept-btn-handler\"]"))).click();
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"PromoteSignUpPopUp\"]/div[2]/i"))).click();
    
        //WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.id("tradingview_")); // Below is the other option I tried.
        WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.className("symbol-list deletable ui-sortable"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame1);
                
        
        List<WebElement> rowelements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div"));
        System.out.println(rowelements.size()); //This prints out rowsize
        int rowsize = rowelements.size(); // This saves rowsize to variable rowsize
        
        List<WebElement> colelements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div"));
        System.out.println(colelements.size());
        int colsize = colelements.size();
        
        for (int i=1; i<=rowsize; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<=colsize; j++) {
                
                System.out.println(driver.findElement
                        (By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div["+i+"]/div["+j+"]")).getText())
            
;           }
        }
        
            
                
    }

}
```

Comment: Please update your question, add selenium version and code output (exception stacktrace).

Comment: Selenium version 4.10.0

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#tradingview_"}